# Different jQuery function based on parent class

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have a switch that changes parent class to a div, and based on that parent class, the links inside that parent do different things. I wrote it like it's CSS :D

```
// if the parent is .major, do this:
$(".major .menu a").click(function(e){
    $(".minor-result").removeClass("act");
    $(".major-result").addClass("act");
    e.preventDefault();
});
// if the parent is .minor, do this:
$(".minor .menu a").click(function(e){
    $(".major-result").removeClass("act");
    $(".minor-result").addClass("act");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Also, there will be seven different parent classes. It can't be a toggle and I really need those add/remove rules for child elements.

I understand that jQuery is binding that function to the existing parent-child combo and changing parent classes doesn't change the function.

Edit:
One cleaver solution would be to put 7 unique links inside each menu li and those links would be display: block/none with CSS, based on parent class. If each link has only one function, there's no longer a problem. But maybe jQuery can simplify it by swapping 7 options.

```js
// swap classes for #scale 
$(".make-minor a").click(function(e){
    $("#scale").removeClass("major");
    $("#scale").addClass("minor");
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(".make-major a").click(function(e){
    $("#scale").removeClass("minor");
    $("#scale").addClass("major");
    e.preventDefault();
});
// here is the part I struggle with:
// if the parent is .major, do this:
$(".major .menu a").click(function(e){
    $(".minor-result").removeClass("act");
    $(".major-result").addClass("act");
    e.preventDefault();
});
// if the parent is .minor, do this:
$(".minor .menu a").click(function(e){
    $(".major-result").removeClass("act");
    $(".minor-result").addClass("act");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.page-body {margin:20px auto;width:200px;}
a {text-decoration:none;padding:5px 10px;display:inline-block;}

.make-minor a {background:blue;color:#fff;}
.make-major a {background:red;color:#fff;}

.major .menu a {color:orange;}
.minor .menu a {color:teal;}

.act {display:block !important;}
.major-result, .minor-result {display:none;}

.major-result a {color:red;}
.minor-result a {color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-body">
  
<div class="make-major"><a href="">make it Major</a></div>
<div class="make-minor"><a href="">make it minor</a></div>

<div id="scale" class="major"><!-- can be .minor -->
  <ul id="wrap" class="menu">
    <li id="one"><a href="">I</a></li>
    <li id="two"><a href="">ii</a></li>
    <li id="three"><a href="">III</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="major-result act">
  <li><a href="">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="minor-result">
  <li><a href="">one minor</a></li>
  <li><a href="">two minor</a></li>
  <li><a href="">three minor</a></li>
</ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve and where it goes wrong..

Comment: I have two options: 
1) 7 show/hide links with CSS based on currently active parent class and each link has a different jQuery function = no problem. 
2) 1 link with 7 different functions that are switched based on currently active parent class = no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four `click` listeners can be replaced with two:

1. Finds a target action name in the class list of a parent, then removes previous and adds the current action to `#scale` element classes.
2. Removes an `act` class from *result* elements, builds the `.ACTION_NAME-result` selector with current `#scale` action name, finds an element using that selector, and finally adds an `act` class to it.

General CSS classes `make` and `result` were added to simplify the script and styling.

Five *color* actions have been added to demonstrate the seven different parent classes. All classes (including *major*, *minor*) are listed in `actions` variable at the beginning of a script.

```js
$(function() {
  // list of action names
  const actions = ["major", "minor", "green", "aqua", "gray", "fuchsia", "orange"];

  // swap classes for #scale 
  $(".make a").click(function(e) {
    const make = $(this).closest(".make");
    const makeActions = actions.filter(function(act) {
      return make.hasClass("make-" + act);
    });
    $("#scale").removeClass(actions);
    $("#scale").addClass(makeActions);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // find an action class and activate its result
  $("#scale .menu a").click(function(e) {
    const scale = $(this).closest("#scale");
    $(".result").removeClass("act");
    actions.forEach(function(act) {
      if (scale.hasClass(act)) {
        $("." + act + "-result").addClass("act");
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.page-body {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 200px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Make links */

.make a {
  color: #fff;
}

.make-minor a {
  background: blue;
}

.make-major a {
  background: red;
}

.make-green a {
  background: green;
}

.make-aqua a {
  background: aqua;
}

.make-gray a {
  background: gray;
}

.make-fuchsia a {
  background: fuchsia;
}

.make-orange a {
  background: orange;
}


/* Results */

.result {
  display: none;
}

.result.act {
  display: block;
}


/* Menu and result colors */

.major .menu a,
.major-result a {
  color: red;
}

.minor .menu a,
.minor-result a {
  color: blue;
}

.green .menu a,
.green-result a {
  color: green;
}

.aqua .menu a,
.aqua-result a {
  color: aqua;
}

.gray .menu a,
.gray-result a {
  color: gray;
}

.fuchsia .menu a,
.fuchsia-result a {
  color: fuchsia;
}

.orange .menu a,
.orange-result a {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="page-body">

  <div class="make-major make"><a href="">make it Major</a></div>
  <div class="make-minor make"><a href="">make it minor</a></div>
  <div class="make-green make"><a href="">make it green</a></div>
  <div class="make-aqua make"><a href="">make it aqua</a></div>
  <div class="make-gray make"><a href="">make it gray</a></div>
  <div class="make-fuchsia make"><a href="">make it fuchsia</a></div>
  <div class="make-orange make"><a href="">make it orange</a></div>

  <div id="scale" class="major">
    <!-- can be .minor, .green, .aqua, ... -->
    <ul id="wrap" class="menu">
      <li id="one"><a href="">I</a></li>
      <li id="two"><a href="">ii</a></li>
      <li id="three"><a href="">III</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="major-result result act">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="minor-result result">
    <li><a href="#">one minor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two minor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three minor</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="green-result result">
    <li><a href="#">one green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three green</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="aqua-result result">
    <li><a href="#">one aqua</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two aqua</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three aqua</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="gray-result result">
    <li><a href="#">one gray</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two gray</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three gray</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="fuchsia-result result">
    <li><a href="#">one fuchsia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two fuchsia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three fuchsia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="orange-result result">
    <li><a href="#">one orange</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two orange</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three orange</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works exactly like I wanted! Thank you!